# Handle multiple post request using angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a very large form with html input elements and I am making a post request to webapi when there is change in input value.

It is possible that with in second more than 10 post requests gets fire. Which leads to data inconsistancy. To avoid this scenario I used mutex on server side to handle one request at a time.

```
string mutexName = $"{userId}-{id}";

using (MutexSlimWrapper mutex = MutexSlimDictionary.Instance.GetWrapper(mutexName))
{
    await mutex.WaitAsync();
}
```

Is there any way to handle this scenario on client side like **debounce** ?

Comment: You could use [forkJoin](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61)

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the [valueChanges](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#managing-control-values) property of a [ReactiveForm](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) with rxjs [debounceTime()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) and also pipe rxjs [mergeMap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) to call your api with the changed value:

```
this.form
    .valueChanges
    .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        mergeMap((formData: any) => 
           this.yourService.yourServiceMethod(formData)
        )
    )
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
        // result from the webserver
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the component do something like that:

```
searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {
    this.searchService.search(this.searchTerm$)
      .subscribe(results => {
        this.results = results.results;
      });
  }
```

In the `SearchService` do this:

```
search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
  }

  searchEntries(term) {
    return this.http
        .get(this.apiUrl + term)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Search method takes in a observable of strings, goes through a few operators to limit the amount of requests that go through and then calls a `searchEntries` method. `debounceTime` waits until there’s no new data for the provided amount of time (400ms in this case) until it lets the next data through. `distinctUntilChanged` will ensure that only distinct data passes through. If the user types something, erases a character quickly and then types back the same character, `distinctUntilChanged` will only send the data once.

Finally in your input just do this:

```
<input (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you a combination of the following three RxJS Operators:

`debounceTime` e.g. debounceTime(400). If you do not manipulate the field for 400ms a request is submitted

`distinctUntilChanged` after 400ms (see debounceTime) it will be checked if the content has changed since the last emitted value. If so the next pipe will be called. If the value hasn't changed no request will be sent.

`switchMap` could be used - when a new search is made, pending results are no longer needed --> which means only the most recent result is processed so if the server is slow with answering only the last result will trigger the subscribe.

So the code would look something like

Be aware that this is done by RxJS 6.0 or bigger without rxjs-compat. 
If you use an older version you don't need the pipe.
`yourFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
   debounceTime(400), 
   distinctUntilChanged(), 
   switchMap(res => ...))
.subscribe((val) => ...)`

RxJS 5.0 solution

`yourformControl.valueChanges
   .debounceTime(400)
   .distinctUntilChanged()
   .switchMap(res => ...)
   .subscribe(val => ...)`

Hope this helps.